# Magento e-Commerce cannot generate reports

Tags: magento

Good day,

My magento cannot generate reports from the admin panel. I get the following error:

This report depends on timezone configuration. Once timezone is changed, the lifetime statistics need to be refreshed.
Last updated: Oct 21, 2010 3:04:33 PM. To refresh last day's statistics, click here."

I follow the instruction and refresh the statistics, still same problem. I confirmed the timezone is right and didn't change before...

Please help.

Comment: have you turned on logging and looked in `exception.log`?

Comment: Yes, but nothing to do with the timezone.  This error I found is the exception.log is "exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_CatalogInventory_Block_Qtyincrements' in /home/silverbe/public_html/app/Mage.php:550"

Answer (score 0):

On an unrelated note (and I'm surprised this hasn't been asked here before) the exception `Invalid block type: Mage_CatalogInventory_Block_Qtyincrements` is a common one and has a simple fix. [Download the file given here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/195761/#t243583) then in the base of your Magento dir extract the files and use these commands;

```
patch -p0 < 70178.patch
patch -p0 < 70210.patch
```

Comment: Thanks clockworkgeek. But did you know the solution for the timezone problem to generate report?